DropdownButton in flutter not keeping initial value from Firebase db
I have a DropdownButton where the user can select a US state. When the user saves the data the value selected is saved to a Firebase db document. This works fine.
When I want to retrieve the selected state from the document and populate the DropdownButton with the value held in the document, I don't get it when the screen is finally displayed. I populate a variable called _currentPropertyState with the state abbreviation from the db
I declare _currentPropertyState outside the class so it should be global for the class.
When I trace through the code, I can retrieve the state value and assign it to a variable that I use to assign to the "value" property of the DropdownButton.
Here is the code for the simple DropdownButton:
DropdownButton<String>(
  value: _currentPropertyState,
  items: _dropDownState,
  hint: const Text('Choose State'),
  onChanged: changedDropDownState,
),

Here is the code where I populate the variable _currentPropertyState. Retrieving the data from the db works fine:
  if (trxnSnapshot.data()?['propertyState'] == null ||
      trxnSnapshot.data()?['propertyState'] == "") {
    _currentPropertyState = "Choose State";
  } else {
    _currentPropertyState = trxnSnapshot.data()?['propertyState'];
  }

It's all very simple. I don't do anything with the variable inside the building of the widget tree other than assign it to "value" in the DropdownButton.
Here is a screenshot of the final result:

The DropdownButton should have the value "FL" in it rather than "Choose State".
How do I debug this so I can see where I am losing the data?
I am using VSCode on a Windows 11 machine.
Thanks

How are you telling the view with the DropDown button to rebuild? Typically, you'll have to setState({}) or notifyListeners() depending on what you are using to manage state in your app. If you provide a little more detail on this, I can be of further assistance.

@thenry Thank you for your reply. I do this in the initState() method so it would be fine.

I put setState inside the initState and that fixed it. I thought initState was setting state.

Great. Each time there is a variable change that is associated with a display you will need to call setState so that the build widget will know to fire. I will create an answer for you to check if I have helped you.

If you want to update the display based on a change in variable you will need to rebuild the display. Depending on your state management system this could be done differently.
For example,
_currentPropertyState = trxnSnapshot.data()?['propertyState'];

should be
setState({
_currentPropertyState = trxnSnapshot.data()?['propertyState'];
})

or if you are using ChangeNotifier
_currentPropertyState = trxnSnapshot.data()?['propertyState'];
notifyListeners()

Without knowing the architecture of your application, I can't give an exact answer, but this path should lead you to solving your issue.
